# position fixed still not working

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website and I want the navbar bar to be fixed but its working. I've read a lot of articles but none of the fixes is working for me. I don't know what I've done wrong.
This is how my html and css looks like:

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
}
nav{
  background:#212324;
  postion:fixed;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;  
}

main{
  margin-top:-16px;
  background:red;

}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/goEY18/Logo_Makr_4zk77m.png" alt="logo">
         <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showLinks()"></i>
 <ul id="link-list">
   <li><a href="">Me</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Skills</a></li>
   <li class="third"><a href="">Works</a></li>
   <li id="cv"><a href="">Download CV</a></li>
   <li></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
<section>
<p>There's a lot of text here </p>
</section>
</main>
```

There's a link to the code
https://codepen.io/stel/pen/WKEezJ

Comment: what is a postion?

Comment: Oh my God.Thanks a lot. This is so embarrassing. I've spent more than an hour on this.

Comment: your codepen is working completely fine

Comment: To prevent such mistype errors, use intelligent highlighting in your editor. If you haven't good editor, you may check it in jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qfjkdvmc/1/

Comment: Add position: fixed; within your CSS and don't use tag name directly for applying CSS, a better way is to use the class name for css

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"postion:fixed"  should be "position:fixed" (postion to position)

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
}
nav{
  background:#212324;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;  
}

main{
  margin-top:-16px;
  background:red;

}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/goEY18/Logo_Makr_4zk77m.png" alt="logo">
         <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showLinks()"></i>
 <ul id="link-list">
   <li><a href="">Me</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Skills</a></li>
   <li class="third"><a href="">Works</a></li>
   <li id="cv"><a href="">Download CV</a></li>
   <li></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
<section>
<p>There's a lot of text here </p>
</section>
</main>
```

here is your code https://jsfiddle.net/d49n5w8f/1/

Comment: This is so embarrassing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your css - changing

> postion:fixed;

to

```
position: fixed;
```

will do the trick.

hope this helps :)